# how to get image name in didfinishpickermediawithinfo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a problem,I use global property but I can't take the value in didfinishpickermediawithinfo.

What should I do?

vc.m

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *addImageView;
@property (weak,nonatomic) UIImage *addImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"NAMEEEEEEEEEEEEEE : %@",_name);
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
_addImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];//get user selected image
self.addImageView.image = _addImage;//put to imageview
NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[uuid UUIDString]];
NSString *documentsPath =[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.addImageView.image, 1);//page 278
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

self.name = fileName;

NSLog(@"Name is here %@",self.name);
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];//close imagepickercontroller

- (void)clickUpload:(id)sender {

//UPLOAD NEED IMAGE NAME , so I create a global var.

}
```

I want to get my image name to upload image,but the value is null.

LOG: NAMEEEEEEEEEEEEEE : (null)
     Name is here : A0E2D275-89D9-4067-9090-F6EF71234567.jpg

In didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo function,I get image name successfully. But I pass value to global var failed.

Comment: Store the selected image with a name you give, first?

Comment: excusme , how to do that?

Comment: Images don't have "names".

Comment: sorry, I refresh my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the `AssetsLibrary` framework to do this.
Inside your didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: function, add this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    NSURL *url = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) 
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *imageRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        NSString *fileName = [imageRepresentation filename]; // Your image's file name here
    } 
    failureBlock:nil];
}
```

**UPDATE**

Change this line :

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

into this:

```
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

Comment: I know how to get image name. In didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo function,I get image name successfully. But I pass value to global var failed.

Answer (score 0):

Make the global variable to **strong reference**, like this,

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *name
```